Is it possible to create a graphql server with next.js 15?
I feel I tried everything
src/app/api/gql
//resolver
const charactersData = [
  {...},
  {...  }, 
];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    characters: () => charactersData,
  },
};

export default resolvers;

//schema
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Character {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    status: String!
    species: String!
    gender: String!
  }

  type Query {
    characters: [Character!]!
  }
`;

export default typeDefs;

// router

import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from "@as-integrations/next";
import typeDefs from "./schema";
import resolvers from "./resolvers";

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(apolloServer);

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  return handler(request);
}

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  return handler(request);
}

src/app/page.tsx
"use client"; // This page needs to be a client component

import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const GET_CHARACTERS = gql`
  query GetCharacters {
    characters {
      id
      name 
    }
  }
`;

const DashboardPage = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_CHARACTERS);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Characters</h1>
      <ul>
        {data.characters.map((character) => (
          <li key={character.id}>
            <h2>{character.name}</h2> 
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DashboardPage;

src/app/layout.tsx
import "./globals.css";
import { UserProvider } from "@/context/UserContext";

export const metadata = {
  title: "My Next.js App",
};

const Layout = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <main>{children}</main>
    </UserProvider>
  );
};

export default Layout;

Invariant Violation: An error occurred! For more details, see the full error text at https://go.apollo.dev/c/err#%7B%22version%22%3A%223.12.4%22%2C%22message%22%3A58%2C%22args%22%3A%5B%5D%7D
When I think I fix this, something else comes up. I've been trying for days.
I can get it working if I connect to an external graphql but I want the graphql server to be set up with next.js
(I feel I have copied exactly what every possible repo I found)
I tried adding context provider...
